# How to stop redirecting to another view when multiple select mode is on

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multiple-select

I use the **multiple select** feature of **UITableView**, whenever I click the rows, it shows the detail view of that row. I also set **allowsSelection** to false but it doesn't affect. Here is my code and could anybody suggest on this case?

```
@IBAction func onEmailButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let isSend = (emailButton.title != "Cancel")

        if isSend {
            emailButton.image = nil
            emailButton.title = "Cancel"
        } else {
            emailButton.title = ""
            emailButton.image = UIImage(named: "email_white")
        }

        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = isSend
        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = isSend
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = !isSend
        self.tableView.setEditing(isSend, animated: false)

        contactAgentBottomButton.hidden = !isSend
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = !isSend

    }
```

Comment: did you put `email btn` over the `tableview` ?

Comment: yes, It's over the tableview

Answer (score 1):

the problem is about you set the btn `enable` to `false`, then when you touch it , it can't accept the `touches` then pass to the  `tableView` below.

two ways to solve the problem :

1. set frame or constrains make `btn` not over `tableview`.
2. when begins edit mode , don't change the btn `enable` then just use `return`.like this :

   ```
   @IBAction func onEmailButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
       if isEditing{
          return
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Wilson. :)